# Error Log: Invalid block type

Tags: cart, product-view, error-log

when I call the product detail page my exception.log show me the following Errors:

```
    exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog' in /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/app/Mage.php:603
Stack trace:
0 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
1 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('bundle/catalog/...', Array)
2 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('bundle/catalog/...', 'germansetup.del...')
3 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('bundle/catalog/...', 'germansetup.del...')
4 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
5 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
6 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
7 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(73): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
8 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(144): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->initProductLayout(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController))
9 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(494, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
10 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
11 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
12 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
13 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
14 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/app/Mage.php(692): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
15 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/htdocs/index.php(161): Mage::run('2', 'store')
16
{main}


exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Bundle' in /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
0 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
1 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('catalog/product...', Array)
2 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalog/product...', 'product.info.bu...')
3 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('catalog/product...', 'product.info.bu...')
4 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
5 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
6 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
7 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(73): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
8 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(144): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->initProductLayout(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController))
9 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(492, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
10 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
11 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
12 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
13 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
14 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
15 /var/www/musterprojekt.com/git/20160208/index.php(169): Mage::run('2', 'store')
16 {main}
```

I can't actually find the reason for this.

Comment: can you share your code product detail page?

Answer (score 1):

somewhere in your theme layout files there is this `<block type="bundle/catalog"...>` that should be something else. Try comparing the file in which you find the text above with the same file from the default theme.